# Please help to solve the problem React Hook "useRef"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Hello** please help to solve the problem.

Page about contact form.

I must get data from  with useRef to const {name, email, message}.
And I must definitely use useRef

It is error message, and I fixed photo error page:

src/components/Contact/Input.jsx
Line 33:38:  React Hook "useRef" is called in function "handleSubmit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

How I can fix this problem.

It is source code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch",
    },
  },
}));

const Form = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  //

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");


    const { name, email, message } = useRef("");
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      message: message.value,
    };

    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/contact", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };

  //

  return (
    <div>
      <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          type="text"
          style={{ color: "white" }}
          inputRef={this.name}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Name"
        />
        <TextField
          inputRef={this.email}
          required
          type="email"
          style={{ color: "white" }}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Email"
        />
        <TextField
          inputRef={this.message}
          type="text"
          style={{ color: "white" }}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Message"
          required
        />
        <Button type="submit" id="contacts1" color="primary">
          {status}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

It is error page:
[image]

Comment: I'm not a react dev, but it looks like you need to call the useRef outside of the handleSubmit function... maybe this could help you? https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/

Comment: You will usually get faster and better answers if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `handleSubmit` starts with a small letter, you have to change it to `HandleSubmit` and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Man i had the same issues, here how i fixed the problem:

1. You don't need to import React in order to use useRef.
2. Just import useRef as UseRef and used it.
3. Enjoy! :D

In your case:

```
import { useState as UseState, useRef as UseRef } from "react";
.....
const { name, email, message } = UseRef("");
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but while the above may have solved your personal issue, it is not the root cause for the question at hand here. It is totally fine to import `useRef` in the way that the original poster did above.